# Get custom attribute from product in Magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to fetch some product data based on the products SKU. This is working, but I also need to get a custom added attribute at the same time, named 'sku_supplier'. Is this possible?

This is what I got:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/app/Mage.php";
Mage::app();

$sku = '748547';

$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('neq' => 1));
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
$products->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $sku);
$products->setCurPage(1)->setPageSize(1);
$products->load();

if ($products->getFirstItem()) {
    $product       = $products->getFirstItem();
    $strProdName   = $product->getName();
    $strProdSku    = $product->getSku();
    $strProdSkuSup = $product->getSku_Supplier(); // <= I want to show this
}else{
    $addError          = 'true';
    $addErrorMessage[] = 'Error...';    
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just remove the underscore:

```
$strProdSkuSup = $product->getSkuSupplier();  
$strProdSkuSup = $product->getData('sku_supplier'); //alternative
```

Magento translates snake_case into camelCase when you want to use the magic getters; ie. an attribute with the attribute code `cool_custom_attribute` would translate into `coolCustomAttribute`, i.e. `$product->getCoolCustomAttribute()`.

### Edit:

You *might* need to load a product model as sometimes I've experienced that not all custom attributes are attached when you pull it out of a collection (intended for performance reasons I guess). Something like:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
$strProdSkuSup = $_product->getSkuSupplier();
```

Also, did you know that there's a [dedicated StackExchange site for Magento](http://magento.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Thanks Dencker, I'm afraid it doesn't work, it doesn't return anything. I'm using flat catalog, could that be it? Maybe I need to use another collection?

Comment: Did you try to `var_dump($product->getData('sku_supplier'))`?

Comment: Yeah, that last edit of yours seems to do the trick, I just put it below the line $strProdSku = $product->getSku(); Thanks a lot Dencker :-D

Comment: Just for future readers, was it the `addAttributeToSelect(...)` that did it or loading the model? Anyway, you're welcome - happy coding!

Comment: The declaring of the custom attribute did _NOT_ work, I needed to load product model as described in the beginning of Denckers edit, the first code block. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm going to remove it then so it doesn't confuse anyone : )

Comment: It's because you have enabled flat products and not checked "Use in product listing" in the settings for `attribute_code`. It won't be indexed into the flat tables then.

Comment: @user3338098 Did you remember to reindex and verify that the attribute is indeed represented as a column in `catalog_product_flat_[x]` ?

Answer (score 3):

Use this

`$strProdSkuSup = $product->getSkuSupplier();`

Instead of

```
$strProdSkuSup = $product->getSku_Supplier();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rohit. Please see my comment above.